# Storing Variables on a "Loop by Loop" Basis

Tags: python, loops

For a current project, I am planning to loop a script and store respective variables on a "loop by loop" basis. So far, so standard.

The specific tweak is here however that each loop is generating several variables and not only one (as discussed in other StackOverflow threads). I have already tried a solution based on `for i in elements: output.append(i)`, which however does not take into account that I am dealing with multiple variables with each iteration.

Is there any smart tweak to make this happen? The corresponding part of the code looks like this:

```
# Processing
    for index, row in filtered_dates.iterrows():
        line = row['Text Main']

        # Remove the leading spaces and newline character
        line = line.split(' ')
        line = [val.strip() for val in line]

        # Convert the characters in line to
        # lowercase to avoid case mismatch
        line = [val.lower() for val in line]

        # Remove the punctuation marks from the line
        line = [val.translate(val.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation)) for val in line]
        print(line)
        # Split the line into words
        # words = [val.split(" ") for val in line]
        # print(words)
        # Iterate over each word in line
        for word in line:
            # Check if the word is already in dictionary
            if word in d.keys():
                # Increment count of word by 1
                d[word] = d[word] + 1
            else:
                # Add the word to dictionary with count 1
                d[word] = 1

    print(d)

    # Looping output
    output = []
    elements = [0, 44]
    for x in elements:
        output.append(x)

        # Print the contents of dictionary
        for key in list(d.keys()):
            print(key, ":", d[key])

            # Count the total number of words
            total = sum(d.values())
            percent = d[key] / total

            print(d[key], total, percent)


            with open('Glassdoor_A.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow(["Word", "Occurrences", "Percentage"])
                writer.writerows([key, d[key], d[key] / total] for key in list(d.keys()))
```

Comment: Use a dictionary with the iteration number as the key(s)?

Comment: Yup good point - that's what I tried in fact with `output = [], elements = [0, 40], for i in elements: output.append(i)`. It did not seem to work for a larger number of variables per iteration though....

Comment: If you want to store multiple attributes per iteration of the loop then typically you would use a list (one item per iteration) and each list item would be either a dictionary (multiple key/value pairs) or an object (of a given class, with named properties).

Comment: Guess that's the way to go then, many thanks. I have amended the code in the question text accordingly to highlight the solution. One last thing: the CSV file is only showing the consodlidated data, not the loop by loop data. Does anyone know how I can distinguish between loops in the CSV file?

Comment: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) might help. ... `for i,xyz in enumerate(something):`